# CoreData concurrency (for sync with CloudKit)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency, cloudkit

In one of my apps I would like to enable sync via CloudKit. The app itself stores the data using CoreData. I cannot use CoreData+iCloud because I need to be able to track changes which were made which is not possible with the above mentioned setup.

The obvious challenge which I have relates to the fact that CloudKit operations will be happening on the background thread and so I need to support concurrency with my CoreData stack.

Lets assume that I have some CoreData entity which I want to sync with CloudKit. To do background sync I need to create a separate managed object context. When this context fetches changes made to my entity on other devices I want to save these changes.

However, the problem is that during the execution of fetch user could have changed some attributes of a given entity and I am now stuck with this entity having some important information on both contexts. I cannot just choose between which one to save - I need to merge the changes.

Unfortunately, I do not understand which approach I need to take to be able to manually sync these changes. I have already checked the possible techniques (parent-child, multiple contexts, multiple store coordinators) but I still don't understand which approach I need to choose.

Can someone help me to resolve this confusion?

The most ideal solution for me would be such that I would get a conflict whenever sync context tries to merge changes to the main context which also had some changes. In this case I could easily decide which attributes should be updated, but I really don't know how this can be done...

Comment: If you have time I suggest you read this awesome book: https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/ It finally gave me an understanding how the beast works. It also has a solution for your exact problem as a case-study on conflict handling between different contexts. Comes with access to code too.

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion! I will definitely consider reading the full book. Is there any chance you can at least provide a hint as to what approach is best in my case?

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk hey, did you solve the issue? I’m having almost same problem, sync with cloud gives me a bunch of different conflicts that I don’t know how to solve. Will be so helpful if you will share your solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In Apple WWDC 2014 they did a session on just this in effect. Here is the transcript, you can find the video easily too; assuming your Apple Developer.

http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/231

In in short an Apple engineer goes over a very simple example of using change tokens; an industry standard solution to resolving problem of sorting out data change conflicts.

The Ray Wenderlich web site also has some excellent VIDEOs on cloud kit and core data, it is a subscription service, although well worth the money at just 20$ a month, and no I have no affiliation with him; I'm just a subscriber. Google him and your find his website.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't help to resolve my issue. My problem is that once I receive the update from CloudKit I need to incorporate these changes into the CoreData. The problem is that CloudKit update will finish on the background thread. Hence, I need to find a way of updating my app's data from the background thread and I cannot figure out how best to do it...

Comment: Andriy does this post answer your question :| http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714642/how-to-determine-when-all-images-have-been-downloaded-from-a-set-in-swift/35724979#35724979

Comment: No, it doesn't, because my question is specific to Core Data and not background processes in general

Comment: I tried; my final thought, Ray Wenderlich website has about dozen videos on this subject: maybe you could find an answer there. I can give you the titles, but not much more. Intermediate Core Data: Series Introduction (3:14) [Free]
Intermediate Core Data Part 1: Core Data Stack (15:36)
Intermediate Core Data Part 2: Advanced Attributes (12:28) [Free]
Intermediate Core Data Part 3: Mapping Models (19:20)
Intermediate Core Data Part 4: Fetched Results Controllers (9:09)
Intermediate Core Data Part 5: Managed Object Contexts (11:54)
Intermediate Core Data Part 6: Conclusion (3:13)

Comment: Ray has very good tutorials indeed. However, the only time he touched background threads with core data + cloud kit he presented parent-child contexts model. It worked in his example because he only needed read access on background thread. In my case, however, I need to have a system which could handle writing to core data from background AND main threads with some mechanism to resolve conflicts. Unfortunately, he never covered this topic...