# How to determine when all images have been downloaded from a set in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using the PinRemoteImage library to download images that populate a `collectionView`. I want to update the cell height dynamically based on the image height, so I need to know when all my images are downloaded so that I can reload/invalidate my `collectionViewLayout`.  What's the best way to determine when there are no more images left to download?

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PinCollectionViewCell

       cell.pinImage?.pin_updateWithProgress = true
       cell.pinImage?.image = nil

        if let pinImageURL = self.pins[indexPath.row].largestImage().url {


            cell.pinImage?.pin_setImageFromURL(pinImageURL, completion: ({ (result : PINRemoteImageManagerResult) -> Void in

                if let image = result.image {
                    self.imageArray.append(image)

                }
```

Comment: Simply just check the `count` of imageArray is the same as the `count` of `self.pins` in the `completion` block. And if it is, then it means they're all done.

Comment: Don't do your URL request while trying to display, you'll want to perform that request before you attempt to display. To answer your question, you'll need to look into completion handlers. good luck

Comment: do you really need to wait until everything is returned?  What if you get 99 returned but one failure?  Would it be better to update the display with each return, and present the suer with a gradually improving display?

Comment: @Russell great point, I think this is the direction I'm going to go, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used the PinRemoteImage image library, but replying on completion blocks when your downloading from iCloud doesn't work, cause the daft process backgrounds and then fires your completion clause BEFORE it has downloaded all the data. This is an extract of my CloudKit code I needed to implement to get around that.

It is using an NSOperationalQueue, code here. Warning this code will enter an endless loop if any of your image downloads fails, creating zombie at best, stopping your app at worst.

Note self.filesQ.returnQThumbs is a subroutine that checks the size of the images downloaded, if they are greater than zero it has one, if they are zero/nil its still downloading...it returns the number it found in the array. self.filesQ.qcount() returns the number of images it is looking to download.

```
func preThumb() {

    newQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    let operation2 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        print("Downloaded, you can now use")
    })

    operation2.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 2 completed")
    }

    let operation1 = NSBlockOperation(block: {
        var allclear = 0


        while (allclear != self.filesQ.qcount()) {
            allclear = self.filesQ.returnQThumbs().count
        }
    })

    operation1.completionBlock = {
        print("Operation 1 completed") 

        // your code to display images could go here!

        self.newQueue.addOperation(operation2)
    }

    operation1.qualityOfService  = .Background
    newQueue.addOperation(operation1)
}
```

Obviously, perhaps not you need to run this method BEFORE you start downloading ideally.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, where does your business logic go?  i.e. how do the methods that are doing the actual downloading relate to operation1 and operation2?

Comment: Gary, they run in parallel. You kick off operation1 which loops until all the images are downloaded, when it is complete it kicks off operation 2. Your downloading in the meantime runs on its own thread. You could skip operation2 in your case and display the images in the completion phase of operation1.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant is would my `cell.pinImage?.pin_setImageFromURL` method go inside operation1's block?